# Is Inline CSS/JS Better?

Tags: javascript, css, inline

Trying to test whether it is better to use inline css/js using php to echo the files, or to just have the standerd

```
<link src="foo.css">
<script src="foo.js">
```

elements.

Does anyone know which is better? I would think the inline would be faster, as less requests. I could be wrong though.

Comment: This has nothing to do with php

Comment: Test it and find out?

Comment: Yeah, I suppose it doesn't.. sorry bout that Leri

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does make a difference in how clean and easily readable your code is. Little to no effect on speed I am sure. Your external .js is only being called during/after the page is already loaded, so should make zero difference in speed.